# Can multithreading be coupled with event programming?

Tags: c, multithreading

I have a single thread C program implemented using event driven programming - a callback triggers every time the event happens.

The callback takes way too long to execute (do a bunch of calculations) and this processing time is important. Currently is 500 microseconds and need it to be less than 100.

Most of the calculations are independent, can be done in parallel.

I have a machine with many cores and was thinking if getting multiple threads to make the calculations in parallel could be possible / of help.

I think that the approach in which at the beginning of the callback I generate multiple threads, and then send the different calculations to the multiple threads will not work well because generating the threads takes time.

Is it possible to have a few threads up, waiting to be used, and that every time the callback is triggered I can send the calculations there without having to generate the threads in each callback?

Comment: You might want to search for and read about *thread pools*.

Comment: Which RTOS are you using?

Comment: What are the sources of events in your system? If it is socket only in modern Linux there is very simple and effective solution. You may start some processes and listen to the same IP/port using SO_REUSEPORT.

Comment: @Lundin not using a rtos but planning to do so. Was thinking on a Linux from wind river. Any other options you can suggest?

Comment: @Joe I'm just giving a nudge that your real-time requirements make no sense without a RTOS. Which makes me wonder how you even benchmark this. If you get 500us accuracy on plain Linux, then that's some sort of magical miracle. Or far more likely, your benchmarking method is incorrect. A context switch may cause any manner of delay and there's no guarantees about anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a thread pool for this (often called a *worker pool*).  The basic idea is create some number of threads in advance and have them all sleep, waiting on a semaphore whenever there is no work to do.

Your code will be simpler if you can get away with one thread for each processing task, but you can also implement it (carefully) with a queue, where each worker tries to handle the next job in the queue and then sleep when the job queue is empty.

Either way, a single round of processing will look something like this:

1. assign or queue tasks to your worker pool
2. notify worker pool to wake up and begin processing tasks
3. wait for worker pool to signal all tasks complete (*)

(*) remember, "all tasks complete" is not the same as "task queue empty"

Now your main timing bottlenecks will depend on the mutex/semaphore implementation and your OS thread scheduler.  It may be appropriate to set a high priority on all your worker threads.

If you have events at regular intervals, a common improvement to the above is to also double-buffer (i.e. output the result for the previous event, and assign the workers to begin processing input for the current event).  To achieve that, you would move step 3 to happen before step 1.

This may or may not be suitable for your purposes.  But it can provide some extra leeway with timing, if you're still having trouble processing fast enough.  Try something simple first.  Problems like this can get hairy very quickly when you start introducing extra requirements.